# python selenium cannot locate clickable play button on mobile version of webpage

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am having a hard time locating the play element on a mobile version of a webpage (my python script is passing a mobile user-agent in the header.)

the website url is below (**NOTE: must be accessed with a mobile user-agent else it won't show the correct page and reverts to standard browser page instead**)

https://m.soundcloud.com/mbmproductions/sets/mark-berrys-playlist

Using inspect in the browser, I have been unable to work out what exactly is needing to be clicked to start it playing. The entire image area around the play button seems to work if I click on it manually, but no element listed by inspect seems to work when using the script to start it playing.

Can anyone explain how to find the correct clickable element in this link so I can add it to a script in order to click it and start it playing. Ideally using XPATH as per my code below, but class or ID or anything would do if it works, even javascript if I have to.

```
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, targetelement))
    )
    element.click()
```

Comment: I find this: <div class="playlist__playButton g-play-button"></div> , and css selector ".playlist__playButton.g-play-button"

Comment: I have tried using those but it fails...
my code:
pressplay = '//div[@class="playlist__playButton g-play-button"]'

driver.find_element_by_xpath(pressplay).click()

My error message:
Error: Message: unknown error: Element <div class="playlist__playButton g-play-button"></div> is not clickable at point (517, 594). Other element would receive the click: <div class="playControls">...</div>

Comment: Try to use ActionChains to move_to_element and click() : https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html

Comment: using ActionChains I did find a solution, but as I initially suspect the class 'playlist_PlayButton' was not the clickable item. The item I needed to click was the '.g-image-fill' and the code worked as per the checked answer from john after a bit of adaptation. @Yun thanks for putting me on the right road to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make some amendment to your script. Use action instead of click(). Change clickable explicit to presence.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC. presence_of_element_located
((By.CLASS_NAME, ‘g-header-artwork-controls’))
    )

el = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(“.playlist__playButton.g-play-button")
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el).click(el).perform()
```

Comment: problem solved. I suspected the button was actually a red herring, it was. so what needed to be clicked was the surrounding area. I changed  one line of code in yours and it now works....el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".g-image-fill")

Comment: incidently I also found the script works if I drop off webdriver. from the code line... `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el).click(el).perform()`